# Bitwise And Operator

Tags: binary

Can someone explain this in simpler terms?

The binary representation of 170 is `0000 0000 1010 1010`. The binary representation of 75 is `0000 0000 0100 1011`. Performing the bitwise AND operation on these two values produces the binary result `0000 0000 0000 1010`, which is decimal 10.

```
0000 0000 1010 1010
0000 0000 0100 1011
-------------------
0000 0000 0000 1010
```

This will make will click for me once I know what is being done. I have a basic understanding of binaries and know a few off the top of my head... like 1 represented in binary would be `00000001` and 2 would be `00000010` and 3 would be `00000011` and 4 would be `00000100` and 5 would be `00000101` and 6 would be `00000110`. So I understand what is going on when you got up a digit each time.

I also understand what is going on when this sql developer is subtracting, but not something is missing when she uses t-sql code to find her answers.... in regards to what is stated in this link.

http://sqlfool.com/2009/02/bitwise-operations/

Comment: `0 & 0 == 0`, `0 & 1 == 0`, `1 & 0 == 0` and `1 & 1 == 1`. Basically, both values must be 1 in order for the result to be 1. You do this for each vertical pair in the two numbers.

Answer (score 3):

Look at the individual binary digits in your example as columns.  If there is a 1 in *both input rows* of a particular column, the output is 1 for that column.  Otherwise it is 0.

The AND operator can be used to "mask" values.  So if you just want the first four low-order bits of a number, you can AND it with 15, like this:

```
0010 1101 1110 1100
0000 0000 0000 1111
-------------------
0000 0000 0000 1100  <-- the value of the first four bits in the top number
```

That's what is happening in the SQL example you linked.

```
freq_interval is one or more of the following:
1 = Sunday
2 = Monday
4 = Tuesday
8 = Wednesday
16 = Thursday
32 = Friday
64 = Saturday
```

Corresponds to the bit masks:

```
0000 0001 = Sunday
0000 0010 = Monday
0000 0100 = Tuesday
0000 1000 = Wednesday
0001 0000 = Thursday
0010 0000 = Friday
0100 0000 = Saturday
```

Comment: I would vote you up, but I don't have enough of a rep, but THANKS!!! So obvious after you pointed it out.