# Bitwise '&' operator

Tags: c, bitwise-operators

I am lacking some basic understanding in bitwise '&' operator.

```
5 = 101
4 = 100
```

So why the output of the below `if` condition is *true* cause and of bits `101 & 100` should be *false*:

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
   if(5&4)
      printf("Yes\n");
}
```

Comment: Why you think it should be false?

Comment: In C, everything that is non-zero is "true".

Comment: cause if we compare each bit of 5 and 4 both of them does not exactly have same bits on

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bitwise And Operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15557063/bitwise-and-operator)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

5 is 101.

4 is 100.

`5 & 4` is **not** 0:

```
101 
100 &
↓↓↓
100
```

Problem solved ✓

---

**Clarification**:

In C, every non-zero value satisfies the `if` condition. Meaning, if you write:

```
if (-5) {
  if (100) {
     // reachable code
  }
}
```

Whereas:

```
if (0) {
  destroyTheWorld(); // we are safe
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
5 - 101
4 - 100
5&4 - 100
```

It is true.

Answer (score 3):

Understanding bitwise operator truth tables is crucial.  Consider the following, where `A` and `B` are inputs and `Y` is the output.

**& (Bitwise And)** When inputs A and B are true, output is true; otherwise output is false

```
A   B   Y
---------
0 | 0 | 0
0 | 1 | 0
1 | 0 | 0
1 | 1 | 1
```

**| (Bitwise Or)** When A or B or both inputs are true output is true; otherwise output is false

```
A   B   Y
---------
0 | 0 | 0
0 | 1 | 1
1 | 0 | 1
1 | 1 | 1
```

**^ (Bitwise X-Or)** When A and B are opposite states, output is true; otherwise output is false

```
A   B   Y
---------
0 | 0 | 0
0 | 1 | 1
1 | 0 | 1
1 | 1 | 0
```

**! (Bitwise Not)** Output is the opposite state of the input

```
A   Y
-----
0 | 1
1 | 0
```

**Your Equation** (5 & 4) == (0101 & 0100) == 0100 == 4 == true

```
  0101
& 0100
------
  0100
```

Answer (score 2):

Because `0b100 & 0b101` equals `0b100` and the latter does not equal `0`.

Answer (score 1):

```
0b101 & 0b100 = 0b100
```

or

```
5&4 = 4
```

and 4 is non-zero and prints `Yes`

Answer (score 1):

It enters the if condition. Because after the `&` operation it returns *non-zero* value. In C, for all non-zero value it's like returning true.