# Meaning of "& 1" in a Javascript return statement?

Tags: javascript, function, return, logic

What does "& 1" mean at the end of a return statement in Javascript?  For example,
`return name.charCodeAt(0) + name.charCodeAt(1) & 1;`

I'm guessing it's something to do with logic.  But then wouldn't it be asking if 1 evaluates to nonzero?  That seems pretty useless.

Comment: it's a [bitwise operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20468963/bitwise-operator)

Comment: as @Nicolas said, it's a bitwise and operator. It scope only affects `name.charCodeAt(1)` and `1`. If `name.charCodeAt(1)` is even, then the hole expression is `name.charCodeAt(0) + 1`, otherwise is `name.charCodeAt(0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the bitwise AND operator. It "returns a 1 in each bit position for which the corresponding bits of both operands are 1s." [-From MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators)